# App to display safari cookies on iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mobile-safari

I want to make an app in iphone such that it displays the history of safari browser in iphone. Means I want to access safari cookies through other app. This is the first time m placing a query on overflow...... can anybody please let me know about this... please do reply

Answer (score 0):

i don't know whether it will work or not but you can try this using NSHTTPCookie and NSHTTPCookieStorage classes...

code would be similar this

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];         

    NSURL *URL;
    NSArray *cookies;
    NSString *cookieString = @"";


    cookies = [cookieStorage cookies];

    if([cookies count] > 0) {
        NSHTTPCookie *cookie =[cookies objectAtIndex:0];    
        cookieString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@=%@", [cookie name], [cookie value]];            
        NSLog(cookieString);
    }
```

Comment: i think it is giving the cookie name and value of the brouser that i open within the app and not of safari....can u  please let me know the code to check it for history because cookies are not readable. i have read it somewhere that the path to history .plist file is /private/var/mobile/Library/Safari/History.plist
 can i access this path through my app.             ............would really appretiate you comments buddy.